# Assign jQuery click event to the everything in the body except a few divs and their children

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

When I press a div on my page, a popup appears. When you click the div again, the popup disappears. When you click outside of the div, the popup disappears - all looking good so far.

The problem is, when I click the popup, I want it so that the popup and it's children are clickable (they're links inside an unordered list), but I can't seem to get that to work. Here is my code:

```
        $(function () {
            $('#messageNotification').click(function (event) {
            $("body").one('click', function () {

                jQuery(".userInfo").fadeOut();
            });
            event.stopPropagation();
        });


          <body>
            <div id="messageNotification"><div class="notif same">0</div></div>
            <div id="messages">
                <ul class="userInfo" style="">
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             
          </body>
```

Comment: Which element is the popup? Where's the code to display the popup?

Answer (score 7):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can filter by selector. For example:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){ ... });
```

This would bind the `click` event to all elements matching the selector `a`.

If you want to bind the click to all elements *not* matching your popup, you could do something like:

```
$('body').on('click', ':not(#popup)', function(){ // code to dismiss popup here });
```

See the jquery documentation for [:not()](http://jqapi.com/#p=not-selector) and [.on()](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) for more info...